# Basic Auth Request from Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, http, httprequest, basic-authentication

So far I have this command to use in the terminal to make a GET request to readme.io api

```
curl https://dash.readme.io/api/v1 -X GET -u API_KEY:
```

PASSWORD VALUE is empty, the curl command works just fine in the terminal.

How do I do that with node.js
I have this.

```
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic API_KEY:'
    }
};

fetch('https://dash.readme.io/api/v1', options)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(body => console.log(body))
  .catch(err => console.log('ERROR', err))
```

but it returns:

```
{"error":"Unauthorized","errors":null}
```

Can you please tell me what part did I mistaken?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: because you should replace API_KEY with actual api key

Comment: @Dipakchavda I do mate.

Comment: @ok so can you post your whole code.

Comment: which node module do you used?

Comment: There is -u parameter missing in your request and as document described you do not pass username and password